# ActionScript Bitmap Filter Tweening

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, tween

i can't seem to tween any bitmap filters.  here's my code:

```
var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter();
mySprite.filters = [dropShadow];
var dropShadowTween:Tween = new Tween(dropShadow, "distance", Regular.easeOut, 4.0, 20, 2, true);
```

what is my mistake?  i've also tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var dropShadowTween:Tween = new Tween(mySprite.filters[0], "distance", Regular.easeOut, 4.0, 20, 2, true);
```

Comment: ah.  a bit of googling shows that tweening filters with the built in tween class is not possible.  that's disappointing.  although other free and open source tween classes offer this ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem with the tweening of filters is that you have to reassign them before they change, just changing the value of the dropshadow wont make a difference until you call `mySprite.filters = new Array(dropshadow)` again. Just incase it becomes needed further down the line!

i would personally use [TweenLite by Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) with its FilterPlugins, works a treat!

Comment: ah... this would be an ideal situation to use a TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE event listener.  thanks.

Comment: just noticed that attempting to tween multiple filters at the same time can be catastrophic.

Comment: oh, actually it's not catastrophic.  i forgot to add the new tweens to the class scope.